# .htaccess rewrite rule did not work for my links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My original links like this: `http://sitename.com/ads.php?i=2` and its rewritten types like this: `http://sitename.com/ads/cars/alfa-romeo-spider-in-good-condition.html`
In .htaccess file, I coded like this: `RewriteRule ^ads/([^/]*)/([^/]*).html$ ads.php?i=$1 [L]` but the page did not shown. How can I write rule in .htaccess file.

Comment: ^ads/(.+)/(.+)\.html$ ads.php?i=$1 [L]. $1 = cars, $2 = alfa-romeo...

Comment: I don't see how you expect .htaccess to convert a string like `cars/alfa-romeo-spider-in-good-condition` into a number like `i=2`.

Comment: Now I noticed the error. Thanks azeos and Ultimater. `RewriteRule ^ads/([^/]*)/([^/]*)-([^/]*).html$ ads.php?cat=$1&i=$2&title=$3 [L]`